# Grails, Want to check status of checkbox inside a gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

Something like this:

```
<g:checkBox name="Polish" value="" checked="false"  />
<g:if test="checkbox named polish == checked">
   <g:link action="createPolishPDF" id="${oh.id}">${oh.id}</g:link>
</g:if>
<g:else>
   <g:link action="createPDF" id="${oh.id}">${oh.id}</g:link>
</g:else>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you trying to display something from the GSP when the initial value of the checkbox is checked vs not checked?

Comment: I have a link in the view that will point to different actions depending on the checkbox status.

Answer (score 0):

You have to options here:

1. Perform check based on `params` of previously issued request:

   < g:checkBox name="Polish" value="" checked="${params.Polish}"/>

   < g:if test="${params.Polish}">
     < div>aaa
   < /g:if>
2. Use some javascript functions to show/hide HTML-elements based on checkbox's state:

   < g:checkBox name="Polish" value="" onchange="toggleSmth(this)" />

Comment: what hapenned with wiki syntax?

Comment: It didn't work for me, the test always returns false. I add the complete form to my question.

Comment: you must submit the form with proper params names

Comment: The for is just a list of different objects where I use the ID as a link so I don't use it as a form. When yo click on one of the objects the controller-action is called with the id of the object so I could get a PDF-print of that object. Now I want to be able to choose between a pdf in polish language or the standard language. It would be nice if I could add the checkbox into the params but I can not make it to work.